# Soap API call with certificate in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, soap

I am trying to call soap api in laravel  https://ws.xledger.net/WS/Common/Lib/Export.asmx with certificate. I am getting "Invalid user access" response from server.

I am getting data from their application which is windows(.exe) based where I have to install certificate and save in MMC. I exported certificate from windows and convert it into .pem format with openssl.

Is their any idea to call certificate?

Here is my code:

```
 $export = 'https://ws.xledger.net/WS/Common/Lib/Export.asmx?wsdl';

   $exports = new SoapClient($export);

  $path = file_get_contents(public_path().'/xledger.pem');

     $header = new SoapHeader('https://ws.xledger.net',
        'Certificate',
        $path);

      $exports->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    $entities = $exports->GetGeneralLedgerData(['sUserName'=>$userName,'sKey'=>$key,'sApplication' => $application, 'iEntityCode'=> $entitycode, 'eOption'=> 'Open']);

    $GetEntitiesDataResult =  $entities->GetEntitiesDataResult;
     echo $GetEntitiesDataResult
```

Comment: https://ws.xledger.net/WS/Common/Lib/Export.asmx?op=GetGeneralLedgerData says Test
The test form is only available for requests from the local machine...... so basically you don't have permission to access the service, hence the "invalid user access" message

Comment: https://ws.xledger.net/WS/Common/Lib/Authentication.asmx?op=LogonKey. Here also say request from local machine but I am getting key as a response.

Comment: yes right..you're saying that you're getting the data also from them....  what about the parameters passed to GetGeneralLedgerData ?....

Comment: you're passing  ['sUserName'=>$userName,'sKey'=>$key,'sApplication' => $application, 'iEntityCode'=> $entitycode, 'eOption'=> 'Open']

Comment: , where as  it requires <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="sUserName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="sKey" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="sApplication" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="iEntityCode" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="sFreeText" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="sFilter" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="eOption" type="tns:DataOption"/>

Comment: Does it affect anything?

Comment: I tried putting all remaining values  sFreeText, sFilter but same problem still exist. I have doubt in certificate call.